# Camera not showing anything when rendering

Tags: rendering, camera

I have 2 cameras.
It's working perfectly when I play the animation in preview.

The first camera works perfectly. When I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, it's rendering:
[image: Render]

However, after the frame goes to camera 2, Blender shows this:

[image: Screenshot]

I already looked for a solution on the interned but could not find one (maybe I was not using the right keywords).

Comment: Posting the Blend file for troubleshooting is almost always necessary.

Comment: Please read thruogh the possible causes for blank render on this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Answer (score 0):

Select everything and press W when you are in Object Mode then press Clear All Restrict Render!That should do it!

Comment: i try it but not working

Comment: Check again the position of the second camera...

Comment: what must i check ?
when i alt + a 
it's work fine